# Can't understand the syntax error

Tags: php, jquery

I have a script that "remember" the values in the input fields after a submit.

```
var previousData = <? php echo json_encode($_POST, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?> ;
for (item in previousData) {
    if (previousData.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
        // Set the value to the input with same name
        $('input[name=' + item + ']').val(previousData[item]);
        $('select[name=' + item + ']').val(previousData[item]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get a syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: syntax error

var previousData = ;
```

When I remove `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`, it works perfect. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your code in quotes:

```
    var previousData = '<?php echo json_encode($_POST,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>'; //single or double quotes here
    for (item in previousData) {
    if (previousData.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
      // Set the value to the input with same name
      $("input[name='"+item+"']").val(previousData[item]);   //Double quotes here
      $("select[name='"+item+"']").val(previousData[item]);   //Double quotes here
```

Comment: Thank your four your answer.

But this dosent work. The values is not remembered after the submit. Can u help me? But why should I wrap it in quotes, when it works perfectly without JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your `previousData` value in quotes `' '` or double quotes `" "`:

```
var previousData = '<?php echo json_encode($_POST,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>';
```

Comment: why should I wrap it in quotes, when it works perfectly without JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE?

Answer (score 0):

Quotes required here:

```
var previousData = '<?php echo json_encode($_POST,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>';
```

if you need to parse your json then do this:

```
var previousData = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($_POST,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE); ?>');
```

You should parse json with `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: why should I wrap it in quotes, when it works perfectly without JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE?

Comment: Well `JSON.parse()` forms a well formed json string to a valid json data and if that works for you then there is no issue to do the parsing but to me that should be parsed.